# Use default style

Tags: magento-1.9, styles

[image]

How can I use all styles from default theme in Theme 1 without copying all folders? But if I need to change some styles I have to do it in Theme 1's folder. Maybe you have some suggestions?

Comment: I think you have used the wrong tag for your question. It should be Magento 2 instead of Magento 1.9.

Comment: No, its magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Create theme.xml in app/design/frontend/Packagename/Themename/etc/theme.xml

```
<theme>
    <parent>parentpackage/parentheme</parent>
</theme>
```

Define parent theme in this node